# Kotlin kotlinClass.class.getName() cannot return package name but only simple class name

Tags: java, android, kotlin

AClass.class.getName();

if AClass is a java class, this method will return package name and class name.
but when i convert AClass java file to Kotlin file ,it will only return a class name. so system cannot find this class path

the code above

Comment: I'm not a professional in Kotlin, but you could try `AClass.class.getPackage().getName();` and append that to your `AClass.class.getName();` Like so: `String location = AClass.class.getPackage().getName() + "." + AClass.class.getName();`

Comment: thanks, `Class.forName(fragmentName)` if fragmentName is a Kotlin class ,it will throws ClassNotFoundException. not matter fragmentName is complete name. so i was confused

Comment: Did that fix it?

Comment: ```val c = Class.forName(fragmentName)?.newInstance()  fragment=c as Fragment``` fragmentName is a KClass complete name, it solves my problem

Answer (score 54):

there are many ways to get the full qualified name of a java `Class` in kotlin:

get name via the property `KClass.qualifiedName`:

```
val name = AClass::class.qualifiedName;
```

**OR** get name via the property `Class.name`:

```
val name = AClass::class.java.name;
```

**OR** get name via the method `Class#getName`:

```
val name = AClass::class.java.getName();
```

the table of the qualified name of a class as below:

```
|-----------------------|-----------------------|-----------------------|
|                       |          Class        |     Anonymous Class   |
|-----------------------|-----------------------|-----------------------|
| KClass.qualifiedName  |    foo.bar.AClass     |         null          |
|-----------------------|-----------------------|-----------------------|
| Class.name            |    foo.bar.AClass     |    foo.bar.AClass$1   |
|-----------------------|-----------------------|-----------------------|
| Class.getName()       |    foo.bar.AClass     |    foo.bar.AClass$1   |
|-----------------------|-----------------------|-----------------------|
```

Comment: If you added an example input sample and output of each described option, that'd be fantastic.

Comment: @EugenPechanec thanks for your feedback, sir. how about it now?

Comment: thanks, actually [this](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/whats-the-kotlin-way-to-create-a-instance-dynamically/1060) is want i want

Comment: I believe the second and third techniques are exactly the same, as Kotlin exposes Java methods beginning with `.get` as properties: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html#getters-and-setters

Answer (score 10):

**If it is a java fragment**

```
var fragmentSimpleName = FragmentName::class.java.simpleName as String
```

Comment: Thanks. As I understood, the same is for Kotlin fragment.

Answer (score 9):

Try below solution::-

```
var name = MainActivity::class.java.canonicalName as String
```

Comment: Actually，It just a few code be covered into Kotlin, `AClass.class.getName();`this code above was invoked in java class , so i cannot use Kotlin syntax like your answer.

Comment: Actually，It just a few code be covered into Kotlin, `AClass.class.getName();`this code above was invoked in java class , so i cannot use Kotlin syntax like your answer. i want a complete file name,because `Class.forName(fragmentName)` will be invoked in next. fragmentName should be replace by AClass complete name. but AClass is a Kotlin class now, it throws ClassNotFoundException

Answer (score 6):

This is what I use to get class-name.

```
    val TAG = javaClass.simpleName
```

For Android developer's, it's very useful to declare as a field, and call to print logs.

Comment: And what is `javaClass`?

Comment: javaClass is the class in which you type. just type javaClass in any class it'll work.

Comment: Thanks! It shouldn't be used as a constant in `companion object`, rather like a variable. In `compaion object` we can use `val TAG = YourClass::class.java.simpleName`.

Comment: @CoolMind That is long solution, you've to type your class name everywhere you use it. Whereas my line of code can be copied to any class and can be used without any modification.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I am a little bit late for the party, but I do it using hash code of the new instance of the fragment. It is an Int so allows all kinds of tests.

```
 private val areaFragment by lazy { Area_Fragment.newInstance() }

    var fragmentHashCode = fragment.hashCode()
            when (fragmentHashCode) {
                areaFragment.hashCode() -> {
                    myNavigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_area)
            }
```